# Powershell script to change time by filename for each file in directory

Tags: powershell

I have a few thousand pictures & videos in a directory and i want to change all the lastAccess, lastWrite,... dates.

My files are all named like 'IMG_20170101_120000.png'.

I want to change for every File the lastAccessDate as the date is in the filename.

Surely there are also other ways, but i found some statements to run it in powershell

```
$(ls IMG_20170101_120000.png).LastAccessTime = (Get-Date "2017-01-01T12:00:00")
```

But now i want to do this for all these files in the directory automatically.

Somebody who can help me?

Thank you for  your help!

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $YourPath -Filter "*.png"
Foreach($File in $Files){
    try{
    $FileName = $File.BaseName
    $FileName =$FileName.Replace("IMG_","")
    $FileName =$FileName.Replace("_","")

    $File.LastAccessTime = [datetime]::ParseExact("$($filename.Substring(0,4))-$($filename.Substring(4,2))-$($filename.Substring(6,2)) $($filename.Substring(8,2)):$($filename.Substring(10,2))", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", $null)

    }catch{"Wrong filename"}
}
```

Please take a look in the powershell documentation, because your code is hard to read, and will not work.

Comment: Then explain it. You want to have the filename as a LastAccessTime ?

Comment: I have many files f.E. 'IMG_20170101_120000.jpg' and 'IMG_20170205_245939.png',..

I want that this script change for every picture the lastAccess changed to the time written in the filename:

IMG_20170101_120000.jpg (LastAccessDate = 2017, Jan 01 12:00:00)
IMG_20170504_185837.png(LastAccessDate = 2017, Mai 04 18:58:37)

That i take the date and time out of the title and use it to change the lastaccess times by the filename.

Thank you for your help

And PS. the code which i sent, works like this. But i have to do for every file manualy :(

Comment: now the code should work like you want. But when the filename has a diffrent format the code will not work. And to your code, this is not how you write nice powershell code, take a look into the documentation of powershell

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry the code don't work.. i tried it in a directory with 20 files. I got 3 times the text 'Wrong filename'. But there was no change.

Comment: Do some debugging by yourself what could be the error? Tell me the filename which throw an error